# Why can't sudo find a command after I added it to PATH?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to add some command to PATH so that I can use them conveniently, such as:

```
export $PATH = "$PATH:/opt/storm/bin"
```

but sometimes `storm` need root authority, but when I use it with `sudo`, Ubuntu cannot find the command.

```
sudo storm nimbus
```

how can I find these command when I use `sudo`?

Comment: What are permission on that folder and file ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to add the path to the `sudo` path.

Run the command `sudo visudo`

you will see a line like this:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
```

Now add the path of your command here and this should work.

For example:

```
$ sudo storm
sudo: storm: command not found
```

Now add the path as above:

```
$ sudo visudo 

secure_path="......:/opt/storm/bin"
```

save and exit.

now `sudo storm` will just work normally.

**Note** You should also add the path to the default path in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one. It helped and I learned from that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created the alias in the user level. That's why the shortcuts are available at the user level only.

You should add that alias command line to .bashrc file in /root folder and not in /home/user/.bashrc(this .bashrc file belongs to user account not root).

So that you can use your alias command directly in shell when logged in as root.

Comment: what about `/etc/profile`? I add `export $PATH = "$PATH:/opt/storm/bin"` in this file, I think this is global, but I still cannot find this command

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) stackoverflow question can solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

@Maythux explained what is the secure path where sudo searches for executables

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
```

you can add the path directly to the list as the answer suggests, but the better and right way is to create an symbolic link unde /usr/bin

```
sudo ln -s -f  /opt/storm/bin/storm /usr/bin/storm
```